# Update a row based on a value in another row

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am trying to update a value in a table based on a value of another row in the same table.  Using the below table as an example:

```
Student #      Subject       Chosen       Required
001            Maths         N            N
054            Maths         N            N
002            History       N            N
001            Geography     Y            N
001            Physics       N            N
054            History       Y            N
002            Physics       Y            N
```

I want a statement that would allow me to change the 'required' column for a student based on whether they had chosen another subject: e.g. If student 001 has chosen maths, he would not be required to do physics.

So it would look something like:

```
Update dbo.Subject_Choices
Set Required = 'Y'
Where Subject = 'Physics'
AND
{I have literally no idea how to continue this syntax, but it would have to check whether the required Field for Maths for the same student = N}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server?  `dbo` seems like an unusual schema name in Oracle.

Comment: It's a bit risky to store data "computed" from other columns like that, because if the math class is removed for a student, you have to always remember to update required column for physics class. To avoid data inconsistency you can use triggers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work for you (modified my query to mkae sure it's Oracle compliant):

```
UPDATE dbo.Subject_Choices SC
SET Required = 'Y'
WHERE Subject = 'Physics'
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Subject_Choices WHERE Subject = 'Maths' and "student #" = SC."student #" AND Required = 'N');
```

Sample [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2275/4) with how the query works.

Comment: The question is tagged with `Oracle` - `[Student #]` is not valid Oracle syntax; you probably want `"Student #"`.

Comment: Can't SQL Server handle "Student #" too?

Comment: Worked like a dream.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3519896 You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if this worked for your problem.

Comment: Done.  Sorry, I'm fairly new here.  Didn't realise that was a thing.

Comment: @user3519896 Don't worry, it's a cool way of motivating people to help. #gamification